# More bytes sent than what I should receive via socket

Tags: c++, winapi, sockets

in my application I found that I receive 2 bytes more than what I expect. I don't know what these 2 bytes means because in the client I'm logging the bytes sent and I receive all on the server, but after the data I still receive these 2 bytes that crash my program. Why? Any idea?

**EDIT 1**

on the client

```
int sentBytes = send(socket, data, size, 0);
```

and on the server

```
int receivedBytes = SOCKET_ERROR;
char *header = new char[8];
receivedBytes = recv(socket, header, 8, 0);

if (receivedBytes == 0 || receivedBytes == WSAECONNRESET)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    size_t data_size = 0;
    std::istringstream is(std::string(header, 8));

    if (!(is >> std::hex >> data_size))
    {
        char *data = new char[data_size + 1];
        data_size = recv(socket, data, data_size, 0);
    }
}
```

I'm using the win32 message loop with WSAAsyncSelect

**EDIT 2**

I'm using the first 8 bytes to send an hex value that contains the length of the message that I should receive on the server

Comment: Are start and end transmission (STX and ETX) characters being accounted for?

Comment: @Heandel added the code   @Cole sorry, I don't understand, what are you talking about?

Comment: So where do the additional two bytes com in? The received `data_size` is two larger than expected? The second call to `recv()` reads more data than specified in `data_size`? Where do those additional two bytes show up?

Comment: What are the 2 characters you don't expect in the data you are receiving and where are they at in relation to the data you do expect?

Comment: @Cole @sth I correctly receive all my data, I can work with them and they are ok, after the latest recv of my data two more bytes are received (unknown source). This is what I don't understand, in debug mode there seems not to exists

Comment: Do you know what are the values of these 2 extra bytes? Are you using a raw socket?

Comment: I'm using WinSock2 with TCP socket

Comment: I'm building the data to send with a std::string, so when I call mystring.c_str() shouldn't it be alredy null-terminated?

Comment: Can you get the value of these 2 bytes?

Comment: if I attach visual studio to the release build exe process and try to see the value of the "header" variable I see 2 but I cannot see the value of the "receivedBytes" variable

Comment: @Heandel I know but at the moment I didn't find anything about portable boost binary archive

Comment: Can you write the data received to a file and then open it in hex mode to see the value? The best option though is to debug and catch these 2 bytes. BTW, you cannot debug a relese build. For this reason you have the Debug build. F5!

Comment: in debug mode the "receivedBytes" variable is always -1 when these 4 bytes are received and the "header" variable in the debugger is shown as "ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍýýýý««««««««îþîþ"

Comment: Download Wireshark and monitor the packets sent/received, that will give you more information.

Comment: It seems that the string that I send is not null-terminated, could be this the problem? The string that I send is build with (string + string).c_str(), but shouldn't the c_str() method alredy add the NULL-terminator?

Comment: @Tony recv() return me -1 two times after that I read all my data

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't check that you got exactly 8 bytes on the first read. It might be less.
2. I hope this is TCP, since with UDP you'd be reading the next packet with the second `recv()`.

Comment: sure it's TCP. Now I've added in the main if the condition than check if the data size is less than 8 and it doesn't crash anymore, anyway I don't understand why there are these 2 bytes that doesn't figure in the log of the client (sender)